# How does Westworld handle guest-on-guest violence?

Tags: westworld-2016

We've seen guests do pretty much whatever they want to hosts, but what happens should things get ugly between paying customers? Could one complain to management? Would the instigator be kicked out/blacklisted/whatever?

Comment: I would imagine they'd be subject to Nevada State Law.

Comment: Calls for conjecture: the required information has not been disclosed.

Comment: @KerrAvon - I've withdrawn my close vote on the grounds that there is sufficient info available on the website and interviews to answer this one intelligently. I've also upvoted. Good question OP.

Comment: In the original film, guns would not function on humans thanks to a heat sensor that prevented them from firing at anything with a near-human temperature.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was answered in interviews with showrunners Jonathan Nolan and Lisa Joy.
In short, any hosts in the vicinity would seamlessly intervene in any situation *where a guest was liable to hurt another guest.*

> **Q. William is told he can’t get hurt in Westworld. But what about being hurt by another guests? What’s to keep a guest from stabbing him thinking he’s a robot? Is there a safe word?**
>
> **Joy:** *We talked a lot about the rules of the park. A lot of it isn’t made explicit in the series but **there’s something called the Good Samaritan Reflex within the hosts. So say you’re in a bar fight and some guy has a knife and maybe there’s even another guest that you didn’t know and he thinks you’re a host and he’s gonna stab you in the back. In that instance, a good Samaritan host would seamlessly intersect and get in that fight and literally take that knife for you**. Now accidents can happen – falling off a cliff and things like that. But you know it’s mitigated somewhat because even the animals – aside from the flies – are hosts, so no horse is going to buck you to your death.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Westworld showrunners talk second episode twists](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/10/09/westworld-showrunners-second-episode)</sup></sub>

and

> *“Part of what the hosts have been designed to do, we have a feature in
> the program called The Good Samaritan Reflex or Function,” Nolan said.
> “Wherever they can, the park is populated by hosts and part of their
> responsibility, **part of their subconscious programming is to try to
> protect the guests in whatever capacity it can.** So if you’ve got a
> drunken guest who’s careening towards a cliff edge, you’re more likely
> than not to have a host nearby who, without breaking that narrative,
> is going to find a way to gently steer them back. They’re cannon
> fodder on one hand, but they’re also the all-purpose minders of this
> place.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[11 RULES OF WESTWORLD — HBO’S KILLER ROBOT SERIES](https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/article/11-rules-of-westworld-hbos-killer-robot-theme-park-series/)</sup></sub>

We see an example of this in episode 5 when the MiB indicates that he intends to "open up" Dr Ford. The closest host (Teddy) responds immediately and decisively.

[image]

---

As to *consequences*, it's mentioned on the Westworld website that the park's rules specifically forbid attempting to harm another guest. Presumably doing so (deliberately) would result in ejection.

> **Aeden:** *You won’t be in any physical danger at Westworld, though the further
> you get from Sweetwater, the rowdier things can get. **The park only has
> one rule: You cannot hurt another human.***
>
> *The hosts, on the other hand, can be hurt and killed, if that is your
> thing. What more can I explain?*
>
> <sub><sup>[LIVE WITHOUT LIMITS - The Westworld Experience: Live Chat with Aeden](https://discoverwestworld.com/#experience)</sup></sub>

We do know that the park would be covered, at least from a liability perspective.

> *“One of the ideas was sort of layered in the narrative,” Nolan said. “I think **the release that you would sign when you came to this place would be pretty extensive,** would cover a fair amount of injury and risk involved in going to Westworld.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[11 RULES OF WESTWORLD — HBO’S KILLER ROBOT SERIES](https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/article/11-rules-of-westworld-hbos-killer-robot-theme-park-series/)</sup></sub>

In the highly unlikely event of "human-on-human" violence, the waiver terms and conditions listed on the [Official Westworld Website](https://www.discoverwestworld.com/#explore) indicate that these crimes would initially be investigated by the park's own investigative team. If it was determined that a crime had occurred, the details would be passed on to the relevant authorities.

> **3. (c)** *Please act responsibly while a guest at the Mesa Gold resort and while utilizing the Mesa Bar. Please be mindful of other
> guests, families, and children. Please note that while utilizing the
> Mesa Bar, you may interact with I Delos, Inc. employees; any ideas
> pitched to Delos, Inc. employees automatically become the property of
> Delos, Inc., in perpetuity. **Also, any mention of human-on-human
> crime admitted to a Delos, Inc. employee must be brought to the
> attention of Delos, Inc., and if falling within the laws of the
> Territory, may have to be reported to local authorities.***
>
> **5.** *INVESTIGATIONS/VIOLATIONS: If Delos, Inc. or any Delos Entity believes, in its sole discretion, that a violation of those Terms has
> occurred, it may take any and all corrective action it dooms
> appropriate without notice, including contacting local authorities on
> the mainland. All human on human crimes taking place within the Delos
> Destinations compound will first be investigated by Delos, Inc.;
> Delos, Inc. has successfully avoided providing personal data in
> response to a legal process involving outside court entities for its
> entire history of existence. However, **Delos, Inc. reserves the right
> to disclose personal information requested by a law enforcement
> agency, and shall have no liability to you for such disclosure.***

As a minimum, were you to engage in behaviour that was against the park's **primary rule**, I suspect the park would exercise its rights as laid out in the waiver.

> ***Delos, Inc. reserves the right to deny access to all or part of the
> Service to you** or any person in its sole discretion without notice or
> liability of any kind.*

---

Additionally, we learn from the [DelosIncorporated viral website](http://delosincorporated.com/#corp-resources) that guest-on-guest violence is monitored by an automated computer system that focuses on three key elements;

- Ensuring guest groups don't cross each others paths
- Ensuring intra-group fights are dealt with swiftly (by using the hosts as a discreet security force)
- Ensuring that groups with unhealthy dynamics are split up.

> THE SECURITY PANEL’S PROPRIETARY LOGISTIC SOFTWARE SEAMLESSLY WORKS
> WITH HOST PROGRAMMING **TO ENSURE GUEST GROUPS CROSS PATHS AS LITTLE AS
> POSSIBLE—** BUT THERE IS NO FULLY ACCOUNTING FOR THE HUMAN FACTOR OF
> INTRA-GROUP CONFLICT.

and

> AGGRESSION BETWEEN GUEST ID#398436 AND GUEST ID#435873 HAS
> INTENSIFIED. GUESTS NOW ACTIVELY SHOOTING AT EACH OTHER.
>
> STATUS:
>
> **BULLET VELOCITY PROTOCOLS FULLY OPERATIONAL**, AND GUESTS REMAINS
> UNAFFECTED, BUT **MUST DEESCALATE SITUATION**.

and

> GUEST ID#398436 HAS BROKEN A MILK BOTTLE AND IS POSING AN ACTIVE
> THREAT TO GUEST ID#435873.
>
> STATUS:
>
> **GOOD SAMARITAN SAFETY PROTOCOLS FULLY OPERATIONAL, AND DESIRED 10-1
> HOST-TO-GUEST RATIO IS BEING MAINTAINED, BUT MUST DEESCALATE THE
> SITUATION.**

Comment: This answer addresses how guests might be protected but doesn't answer the question which was "what happens should things get ugly between paying customers? Could one complain to management? Would the instigator be kicked out/blacklisted/whatever?"  The question is looking for consequences - not details of the safeguards that may be in place..

Comment: @KerrAvon - It addresses that it's the park's sole rule. I think we can reasonably assume expulsion and/or banning would be the result.

Comment: @KerrAvon - See edit. Attacking another guest would be treated as a crime and details passed on to the authorities on the "mainland", at least according to the official website. Evidently the safeguards in place are sufficient that this has **never happened in the lifetime of the company** which makes the info about safeguards highly pertinent.

Comment: It may be worth noting that in the original movie, the guns had sensors in them that prevented them from firing if aimed at a human being. Of course, that wouldn't prevent patrons from using fists, knives, or other weapons.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - According to Nolan, the guns don't work like the ones in the TV show.

Comment: @Valorum - It was just a side note, really, but I think it's rather sad that they don't. A gun might hurt a guest faster than a host could intervene.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Since the bullets are made of wax and basically "ping" off of the guests, it's quite unlikely that a gun would be of any danger, other than as a club.

Comment: The MIB does a fair amount of sneaking up on individual people unaccompanied by other hosts. If he were to mis-identify a human as a host, I'm not sure how he could be prevented from a mistake. I'm a bit unsatisfied by the reflex explanation.

Comment: @Valorum - good edit: Up-voted now...I think that makes this a really full and thorough answer.